What is the Amiga parallel port hardware protocol for bidirectional transfers?
I’ve successfully made a microcontroller device that bridges the Amiga parallel port in output mode to a network printer.
I understand the port is capable of bidirectional transfers and I can imagine some useful devices that would use that.
I can't find a specification online for the bidirectional handshake. I do see documentation of the port driver level, though.

For the record, two popular devices for the bi-directional parallel port were audio and video digitizers such as PerfectSound and DigiView, respectively.

The parallel port is handled by the MOS Technology 8520 CIA chip. In Amiga, the parallel printer port is mainly handled by PORTB on CIA-A of the two CIA chips.
Regarding the features it has, it can be set to a mode  which allows for hand-shaked bidirectional data transfer on PORTB, which are wired to the printer port data pins.
Writing to the CIA PORTB data port will automatically pulse the CIA PC output pin, which is wired to the printer port DRDY* output pin.
Also the FLAG input pin makes the CIA to latch the data in from PORTB and set an interrupt to CPU which may then read in the latched data. The FLAG input is connected to printer port ACK* input pin.
Of course the PORTB data pin directions are individually settable and the other printer port signals (BUSY, POUT and PSEL) connect to the PORTA of the second CIA-B, with BUSY also connected as serial data and POUT as serial clock, which expands the possibility for many kinds of custom handshakes for various data transfer purposes.

(I assume  DRDY*, is what I've seen labeled as nStrobe) But what's the handshake for incoming data?  Does the amiga side use nStrobe to ack incoming data?
